Photos App-style .matchedGeometryEffect working unexpectedly
I am trying to create a Photos App-style grid with a popout effect. I want the effect to look exactly like the Photos App, wherein the source image is scaled to fill the square frame, and the expanded image is scaled to fit the entire screen. I have been struggling greatly with a few issues:

Getting the image to transition from .fill to .fit as it expands

Having the expanding image not clip itself

Removing the crossfade effect so that the image can transition seamlessly


Requirements:

I need the expanded view to be a new view that is not on screen (ConditionalContent) while the base view is visible

The initial frame is a square, and the image must fill, while the final image is not a square, and must fit

I would prefer not to do complex frame math if it is possible to achieve this effect with built-in APIs (I suspect it is)


Here is my current code:
struct ContentView: View {
    @Namespace var nm
    @State var showing = false

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if !showing {
                Color.blue.opacity(0.2)
                    .overlay {
                        Image("Turtle")
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    }
                    .clipped()
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "id", in: nm)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        withAnimation(.linear(duration: 3)) {
                            showing = true
                        }
                    }
                    .transition(.asymmetric(insertion: .identity, removal: .invisible))
            } else {
                Color.green.opacity(0.2)
                    .overlay {
                        Image("Turtle")
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: showing ? .fit : .fill)
                    }
                    .clipped()
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "id", in: nm)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        withAnimation(.linear(duration: 3)) {
                            showing = false
                        }
                    }
                    .transition(.asymmetric(insertion: .identity, removal: .invisible))
            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}

extension AnyTransition {
    struct InvisibleModifier: AnimatableModifier {
        var pct: Double
        
        var animatableData: Double {
            get { pct }
            set { pct = newValue }
        }
        
        
        func body(content: Content) -> some View {
            content.opacity(pct == 1.0 ? 1 : 0)
        }
    }

    static var invisible: AnyTransition {
        AnyTransition.modifier(
            active: InvisibleModifier(pct: 0),
            identity: InvisibleModifier(pct: 1)
        )
    }
}


Is the green background important? Is that part of your requirement?

This post is very like In Swift, how can I matchedGeometryEffect for a clipped() image without it glitching? and the answer there shows how it can be made to work. A solution is much easier if a single image is moving from one position to another. You said: I need the expanded view to be a new view that is not on screen, but the image is already on the screen, so that seems like a bit of a contradiction. Why exactly can't a single version of the image be used?

See also Swift UI matched geometry effect with clip

Original approach: a transition between 2 images
Your example is performing a transition between two images.
Issues and workarounds

Normally, one image would fade out while the other is fading in. You are using a custom Transition to overcome this. The appearing view is fully visible and the disappearing view is instantly invisible.

The change of scaling is not working because the second image is always scaled-to-fit. This is because it is only shown when the flag showing is already set, so it is scaled-to-fit from the first moment it is visible. This is why there is no animated change from scaled-to-fill to scaled-to-fit.


You can get it working by introducing a second flag that controls the scaling. This needs to be updated in an .onAppear for each view. You need to be careful to use the same animation duration as is being used for the transition.
Updated example
The fully updated example is shown below. This includes the additional flag described above and also the following changes:

The implementation for the image is almost identical for both versions, so it can be factored out into a function.

Your custom Transition is not actually needed. You can get the same effect by using a unity scale transition for both the appearing and disappearing view.

The tinted backgrounds have been dropped.


struct ContentView: View {
    @Namespace var nm
    @State var showing = false
    @State var isLarge = false

    private func theImage(showLarge: Bool) -> some View {
        Color.clear
            .overlay {
                Image("Turtle")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: isLarge ? .fit : .fill)
            }
            .clipped()
            .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "id", in: nm)
            .transition(.scale(scale: 1.0))
            .onTapGesture { showing.toggle() }
            .onAppear { isLarge = showLarge }
    }

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if !showing {
                theImage(showLarge: false)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            } else {
                theImage(showLarge: true)
            }
        }
        .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 2), value: showing)
        .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 2), value: isLarge)
    }
}


Alternative approach: a single image that changes position
Concept
Another way to implement the effect is just to use one image that moves from one position to the other. Using this approach, there is no transition involved.
With regard to your requirements, your conditional content would start off in the smaller (square) position before moving to the full-screen position. In other words, the conditional content does not appear at full size, it changes to full-size after it appears.
Example
The example below illustrates how this can be made to work for a gallery-style view that presents a whole collection of images (which is perhaps what you are aiming at):

As before, a ZStack is used as the top-most container.
A LazyVGrid is used to present the collection of images. This is nested inside a ScrollView
The tiles of the grid show the images using scaled-to-fill. The images are clipped to a square aspect ratio.
Space for the large version of the image is reserved using Color.clear.
The selected image is shown (conditionally) as the top layer of the ZStack. The position and size is controlled using matchedGeometryEffect with isSource: false.
Here too, a separate state variable (a flag) is used to control whether the selected image is shown large or not. When first selected, it is not large, so it is matched to the corresponding grid tile.
The flag is changed in an .onAppear callback. This causes the id for the matchedGeometryEffect to switch to the large placeholder, which in turn causes the top layer to move from the grid position to the large position.
The opacity of the grid cell is modified to give a "ghost" effect for the image that is left behind.
The selection is reset using an .onTapGesture applied to the top layer. This first resets the flag, causing the image to move back to the grid position. When this animation completes, the actual selection is reset.

struct ContentView: View {
    let demoImages: [Image] = [.init(.image1), .init(.image2), .init(.image3), .init(.image4)]
    let columns: [GridItem] = [.init(.flexible()), .init(.flexible())]
    let bigImageId = -1

    @Namespace private var nm
    @State private var selectedIndex: Int?
    @State private var isShowingLarge = false

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {

            // The tiles
            ScrollView {
                LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
                    ForEach(Array(demoImages.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { index, image in
                        Color.clear
                            .aspectRatio(1.0, contentMode: .fit)
                            .overlay {
                                image
                                    .resizable()
                                    .scaledToFill()
                                    .opacity(index == selectedIndex ? 0.2 : 1.0)
                            }
                            .clipped()
                            .contentShape(Rectangle())
                            .matchedGeometryEffect(id: index, in: nm, isSource: true)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                selectedIndex = index // without animation
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
            // A placeholder for the big image
            Color.clear
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: bigImageId, in: nm, isSource: true)

            // The selected image
            if let index = selectedIndex {
                Color.clear
                    .overlay {
                        demoImages[index]
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: isShowingLarge ? .fit : .fill)
                    }
                    .clipped()
                    .contentShape(Rectangle())
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(
                        id: isShowingLarge ? bigImageId : index,
                        in: nm,
                        isSource: false
                    )
                    .onAppear {
                        withAnimation(.easeInOut) {
                            isShowingLarge = true
                        }
                    }
                    .onTapGesture {
                        withAnimation(.easeInOut) {
                            isShowingLarge = false
                        } completion: {
                            selectedIndex = nil // without animation
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
        .padding(10)
    }
}


